# Cannot post umlaut to solr via curl

Tags: curl, solr, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to post `[{"id":1, "name":"Waldenström"}]` to solr with the commands

`curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' --data-binary @condition_synonyms.json -H 'Content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8'`

or

`curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' --data @filename.json -H 'Content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8'`

The field it's going to has

`<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>`

specified in its analyzer, which is working - imports via an SQL query in my data-config.xml  correctly put "waldenstrom" in the index.  After posting via curl, the index has it broken into "waldenstr" and "waldenstrm".

Though I suspect it's a problem with the post encoding, I don't not know for sure if this is a solr or curl question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately my database was not UTF-8 as I had thought, it was latin1.  Using

`curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' --data @filename.json -H 'Content-type:application/json; charset=latin1'`

solved the problem, as the file had been exported from the database.

Answer (score 1):

What error you are getting? Are you using windows? Then you should receive the error `Unsupported protocol: 'http`

So try replacing `'` with `"`. For example:

```
curl "http://localhost/"
```

By default your curl will assume it as POST request, but still also use the `-X POST` parameter as well with your commandline.